# Controlling the on-board FDX and 100Mbit LEDs with a kernel module

Tags: hardware, led

I know that the OK LED can be accessed from `/sys/class/leds/led0`, but the FDX and 100 are not. I can see from `/sys/class/net/eth0/duplex` and `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` that the files seem to correspond with the leds. I can not write to `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` or `duplex`, even as superuser. Is it possible to write to the file from a kernel module? I am on Arch.

Answer (score 1):

Although the [LAN9512 datasheet](http://www.smsc.com/Downloads/SMSC/Downloads_Public/Data_Sheets/9512.pdf) says that the pins used to drive the speed and duplex LEDs can be used for GPIO as far as I can tell there is no support in the linux kernel module to actually switch the pins on the LAN9512 into GPIO mode.

Comment: I am looking to control the FDX, 100, and LNK LEDs from C/C++. According to http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3//viewtopic.php?p=136266#p136266, they are hardwired to the Ethernet chip.

Comment: Right the ethernet chip is the LAN9512, it is also a USB hub. I could not even find any clear information about how to use those pins for GPIO in the LAN9512 documentation, only that that they could be used as GPIO pins.